# How to make Android GridLayout compatible to older version?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, grid-layout

New **GridLayout** for Android 4 is good. Both in terms of code maintainability and performance.

I wanted help with backward compatibility for GridLayout for older version. Waiting for official compatibile package is taking too long. I know its possible and someone did mention that this could be done by copying the class from version 4 platform source.

Would be really great if anybody could guide me how to do this.

For reference please check this post on Google Plus
https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/KbqAxUQTzVf

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A better way of doing this is using Android Support Library.
Since resource files are also involved it cannot be included as .jar library.

Update the android SDK and support files.

1. Add  `your-android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\gridlayout` project to eclipse.
2. Make the project as library.
3. Add this library project to your working project.

To use gridlayout in XML use it like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout> </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Hope that was helpful.

Comment: Also make sure you set up your namespace: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10687429/15882

Comment: How do I do the step `#2` ? I'm having a problem, eclipse does not recognize the `gridlayout` ? It says "Wrong namespace... should use `app:*`"

Comment: @mr5 just follow the official documentation : https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res

Answer (score 5):

Check out this project: https://github.com/dlew/android-gridlayout