# GridLayout (not GridView) how to stretch all children evenly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I want to have a 2x2 grid with a buttons inside. This is only ICS so I am trying to use the new GridLayout given.

Here's the XML of my layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/favorites_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00ff00"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:columnCount="2">
  <Button
      android:text="Cell 0"
      android:layout_row="0"
      android:layout_column="0"
      android:textSize="14dip" />
  <Button
      android:text="Cell 1"
      android:layout_row="0"
      android:layout_column="1"
      android:textSize="14dip" />

  <Button
      android:text="Cell 2"
      android:layout_row="1"
      android:layout_column="0"
      android:textSize="14dip" />
  <Button
      android:text="Cell 3"
      android:layout_row="1"
      android:layout_column="1"
      android:textSize="14dip" />
</GridLayout>
```

The problem is that my views do not stretch evenly for each row. This causes a lot of extra space to the right of my GridLayout.

I tried setting `layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"` but that only applies to the **last** view on the row. This means Cell 1 stretches all the way to give enough space for Cell 0.

Thoughts on how to tackle this?

Comment: Why didn't you set specific layout_width and layout_height sizes on these Button elements?

Comment: Why not use TableLayout in your case?

Comment: In Lollipop we can now use the android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout, column count of 3, and then have a <TextView> <Space app:layout_columnWeight="1"/> <TextView> per each colum to achieve the desired effect without all the extra overhead, unless you are building exclusively for SDK 21 and then you can use the normal GradLayout

Comment: Better is to use linear layout with android:layout_width="0dp" and android:layout_weight="1". https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear#equal-weight

Answer (score 84, accepted):

***UPDATE**: Weights are supported as of API 21. See [PaulT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30245753/984780) for more details.*

There are limitations when using the GridLayout, the following quote is taken from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html).

> "GridLayout does not provide support for the principle of weight, as
> defined in weight. In general, it is not therefore possible to
> configure a GridLayout to distribute excess space in non-trivial
> proportions between multiple rows or columns ...  For complete control
> over excess space distribution in a row or column; use a LinearLayout
> subview to hold the components in the associated cell group."

Here is a small example that uses LinearLayout subviews. (I used Space Views that takes up unused area and pushes the buttons into desired position.)

```
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="1"
>
    <TextView
        android:text="2x2 button grid"
        android:textSize="32dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:text="Button 2" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 3" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:text="Button 4" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: This looks like it works. I was trying to avoid that but I dont see another way of getting around this. I could probably write my own ViewGroup class that properly measures and layout its children.

Comment: This GridLayout with a column of 1 is pretty much LinearLayout in vertical orientation. It makes the layout more complicated. GridLayout is supposed to simplify and take away nested layout.

Comment: Just found a way! android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal". In case you are using the Support Library, then change it to grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"

Comment: I agree with Win Myo Htet. This seems to be the answer Android is suggesting, but I fail to see how it is an improvement over a LinearLayout. I thought the reason for GridLayout was to avoid nested LinearLayouts? Now I can't see a use case for GridLayout that makes sense.

Comment: @Mitch It seems the GridLayout plain isn't supposed to be used in this kind of instance. GridLayout, as far as I can tell from the docs, is supposed to help for much more complicated layouts. Imaging a layout where you want to have an small image in the top right corner, a main logo in the center and 3 text fields that should be aligned halfway between the left of the small image and the right of the center logo. GridLayout makes that simple. If you want 3 buttons evenly spaced horizontally, then LinearLayout is still the simplest.

Comment: As of API 21, weight is supported

Comment: The version of GridLayout in the Support Library supports weights and is backwards compatible to API 7. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html

Comment: This answer is almost perfect, except it forgets to mention you need to add
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1'
to your build.gradle file

Comment: Better is to use linear layout with android:layout_width="0dp" and android:layout_weight="1". https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear#equal-weight

Answer (score 349):

Starting in API 21 the notion of weight was added to GridLayout. To support older android devices, you can use the GridLayout from the v7 support library.

The following XML gives an example of how you can use weights to fill the screen width.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/choice_grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="4dp"

    grid:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    grid:columnCount="2"
    grid:rowOrderPreserved="false"
    grid:useDefaultMargins="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FF33B5E5"
        android:text="Tile1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FF33B5E5"
        android:text="Tile2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FF33B5E5"
        android:text="Tile3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FF33B5E5"
        android:text="Tile4" />

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Comment: This answer should be higher up.

Comment: Can this be used to fill both vertical and horizontal at the same time? I want an evenly stretched 3x3 layout but trying to have both weights doesn't work.

Comment: A special case of mine was where I had to use a `FrameLayout` which contained a `Button and an `ImageView` (in order to have an icon overlaid on a button which showed visual feedback when touched... long story) as part of a keypad. Setting `columnWeight` and `gravity` on every other `Button` worked fine, but broke on the `FrameLayout`. Leaving it out just for the `FrameLayout` made everything lay out evenly as expected.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the v7-support version of GridLayout, I had no idea it existed

Comment: the key is the combination of `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `grid:layout_columnWeight="1"`. More generally to make cells not stretch BOTH *horizontally* AND *vertically* use `android:layout_width="0dp"`, `android:layout_height="0dp"`, `grid:layout_columnWeight="1"` & `grid:layout_rowWeight="1"`

Comment: Please consider [including dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9126780/1358777)

Comment: Hello, interesting answer but how is it possible to add    grid:layout_columnWeight="1" programmatically for inflated childrens?

Comment: dependency 
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'

Comment: @S.D. why?! It's not a direct answer to the question that's why should not be accepted answer. It applies to "horizontal-stretch" only.

Comment: I'm using Lenovo Android 6.0, but the children are not visible, although they appear in Preview Panel in Android Studio.

Answer (score 81):

[image]

Appcompat21 `GridLayout` has the column and row weights which can be used like below to evenly create each grid item in the gridlayout like the image above.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    grid:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    grid:columnCount="4" >

    <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
        style="?buttonStyle"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="-1"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
        grid:layout_gravity="fill" />
    ...
</<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Comment: how do you center child views if i have only two colums!

Comment: `compile "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:$supportVersion"`

Comment: In my case, after adding the compile directive - additionally had to provide this "include" call in the xml in order to be able to access the grid attributes (like `app:columnCount="2"`) : `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout"`

Answer (score 58):

Starting in API 21 without v7 support library with ScrollView:

[image]

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="2"
            >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="Tile1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:text="Tile2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Tile3" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="Tile4" />

    </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 36):

You can set width of every child dynamically:

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams params = (GridLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = (parent.getWidth()/parent.getColumnCount()) -params.rightMargin - params.leftMargin;
    child.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: seems to break when `useDefaultMargins="true"` - works perfectly with them set to `false`

Answer (score 18):

This is the right answer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/favorites_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00ff00"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:columnCount="2">
    <Button
        android:text="Cell 0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:textSize="14dip" 
        />
    <Button
        android:text="Cell 1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:textSize="14dip"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Cell 2"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:textSize="14dip"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:text="Cell 3"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:textSize="14dip"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"/>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Sry for commenting so late but please add a little explanation to your answer

Comment: Attribute layout_columnWeight is only used in API level 21 and higher

Answer (score 16):

Try adding the following to your GridLayout spec. That should work.

```
android:useDefaultMargins="true"
```

Comment: And with that, I can call it a GridLayout again!

Comment: Should but actually doesn't.

Answer (score 7):

I finally found the solution. As Rotemmiz said, you have to do it dynamically afterwards. This code stretches the buttons to fill the view horizontally, but the same can be done for vertically.

```
public void fillview(android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout gl)
{
    Button buttontemp;

    //Stretch buttons
    int idealChildWidth = (int) ((gl.getWidth()-20*gl.getColumnCount())/gl.getColumnCount());
    for( int i=0; i< gl.getChildCount();i++)
    {
        buttontemp = (Button) gl.getChildAt(i);
        buttontemp.setWidth(idealChildWidth);
    }
}
```

(The 20 is for the internal and external padding and margins. This could be done more universally, but this is far cleaner)

Then it can be called like this:

```
    android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout gl = (android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttongrid);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = gl.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {@Override public void onGlobalLayout() 
    {

            android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout gl = (android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttongrid);
            fillview(gl);

            ViewTreeObserver obs = gl.getViewTreeObserver();
            obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    }});
```

It must be done with an observer because we need to wait for the view to be drawn before we call the views.

Answer (score 7):

In my case I was adding the buttons dynamically so my solution required some XML part and some Java part. I had to find and mix solutions from a few different places and thought I will share it here so someone else looking for the similar solution might find it helpful.

First part of my layout file XML...

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/gl_Options"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    grid:useDefaultMargins="true">
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

`grid:useDefaultMargins="true"` is not required but I added because that looked better to me, you may apply other visual affects (e.g. padding) as mentioned in some answers here. Now for the buttons as I have to add them dynamically. Here is the Java part of my code to make these buttons, I am including only those lines related to this context. Assume I have to make buttons from as many `myOptions` are available to my code and I am not copying the OnClickListener code as well.

```
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout;   //Reference to Library

public class myFragment extends Fragment{
    GridLayout gl_Options;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        gl_AmountOptions = (GridLayout)view.findViewById( R.id.gl_AmountOptions );
        ...
        gl_Options.removeAllViews();     // Remove all existing views
        gl_AmountOptions.setColumnCount( myOptions.length <= 9 ? 3: 4 );  // Set appropriate number of columns

        for( String opt : myOptions ) {
            GridLayout.LayoutParams lParams   = new GridLayout.LayoutParams( GridLayout.spec( GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f), GridLayout.spec( GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f));
            // The above defines LayoutParameters as not specified Column and Row with grid:layout_columnWeight="1" and grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
            lParams.width = 0;    // Setting width to "0dp" so weight is applied instead

            Button b = new Button(this.getContext());
            b.setText( opt );
            b.setLayoutParams(lParams);
            b.setOnClickListener( myClickListener );
            gl_Options.addView( b );
        }
    }
}
```

As we are using GridLayout from support library and not the standard GridLayout, we have to tell grade about that in `YourProject.grade` file.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: The GridLayout.LayoutParams with GridLayout.spec( GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f) worked great only when grid:useDefaultMargins was false. Also, lParams.width = 0 seems like it has no use since width and height are set by LayoutParams.

Answer (score 5):

You can make this lot faster by overriding ViewGroup onLayout method.
This is my universal solution:

```
package your.app.package;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class GridLayout extends ViewGroup {

    public GridLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        final int columns = 2;//edit this if you need different grid
        final int rows = 2;

        int children = getChildCount();
        if (children != columns * rows)
            throw new IllegalStateException("GridLayout must have " + columns * rows + " children");

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();


        int viewWidth = width / columns;
        int viewHeight = height / rows;

        int rowIndex = 0;
        int columnIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < children; i++) {
            getChildAt(i).layout(viewWidth * columnIndex, viewHeight * rowIndex, viewWidth * columnIndex + viewWidth, viewHeight * rowIndex + viewHeight);
            columnIndex++;
            if (columnIndex == columns) {
                columnIndex = 0;
                rowIndex++;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**
Don't forget match_parent for children!

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Comment: Could be good, but needs support for children padding & margin

Comment: Children padding is supported, because it's attribute set on child. To add margin support, just modify line with "layout" function as follows (where margin variable is margin in pixels): `getChildAt(i).layout(viewWidth * columnIndex + margin, viewHeight * rowIndex + margin, viewWidth * columnIndex + viewWidth - margin, viewHeight * rowIndex + viewHeight - margin);`

Answer (score 4):

Here you are :

```
Button button = new Button(this);
// weight = 1f , gravity = GridLayout.FILL 
GridLayout.LayoutParams param= new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(
            GridLayout.UNDEFINED,GridLayout.FILL,1f),
            GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED,GridLayout.FILL,1f));
// Layout_height = 0 ,Layout_weight = 0
params.height =0;                                                                                                           
params.width = 0;
button.setLayoutParams(param);
```

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I could find is to use a linear layout(horizontal) for each row you want and within it assign the button (cell) width to 0dp and the weight to 1. For each of the linear layouts(rows) assign the height to 0dp and the weight to 1. 
Find the code below- also  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" is used to align the buttons in a row in case they contain variable length text.
Use of 0dp and weight it a pretty neat yet not so well known trick.

```
<LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@drawable/button_bue_3d"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_row1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="false"
                   android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="ssssssssssssssssssssssssss" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="sggggggg" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_row2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="0dp"

                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="s" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="false"
                     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="s" />


            </LinearLayout>


       </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Result :

[image]

Try something like this :

```
    final int MAX_COLUMN = gridView.getColumnCount(); //5
    final int MAX_ROW = gridView.getRowCount(); //7
    final int itemsCount = MAX_ROW * MAX_COLUMN; //35

    int row = 0, column = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
        ImageView view = new ImageView(this);

        //Just to provide alternate colors
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }

        GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(row, 1F), GridLayout.spec(column, 1F));
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
        gridView.addView(view);

        column++;

        if (column >= MAX_COLUMN) {
            column = 0;
            row++;
        }
    }
```

If you want specific width and height for your cells, then use :

```
     params.width = 100; // Your width
     params.height = 100; //your height
```

Answer (score 2):

i have same problem and i think just set width and height programmatically :

set width of button's with metrics.widthPixels / 2  metrics is object of DisplayMetrics.

```
 GridLayout gridLayout=findViewById(R.id.grid);
    for (int i = 0; i <gridLayout.getChildCount() ; i++) {
        View view= gridLayout.getChildAt(i);
        if(view instanceof Button){
            Button btn = (Button) view;
            btn.setWidth(200);//metrics.widthPixels / 2
            btn.setHeight(200);//metrics.heightPixels / 7
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to have a centered table with the labels right aligned and the values left aligned. The extra space should be around the table. After much experimenting and not following what the documentation said I should do, I came up with something that works. Here's what I did:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Short label:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/start_time"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="Long extended value" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="A very long extended label:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/elapsed_time"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="Short value" />
</GridLayout>
```

This seems to work but the GridLayout shows the message:

"This GridLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is useless"

Not sure why it is "useless" when it works for me.

I'm not sure why this works or if this is a good idea, but if you try it and can provide a better idea, small improvement or explain why it works (or won't work) I'd appreciate the feedback.

Thanks.

Comment: This looks good in the layout editor, but fails when it runs. :-(

Comment: The "parent is useless" message is because you have a wrap_content inside a wrap_content and it is the only element in there as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly old question, but obviously of interest to a lot of people. For a simple layout of 4 buttons like this, it seems that a TableLayout is the easiest way to accomplish the desired result.

Here's some example code showing the first 2 rows of a table with 6 columns spanning the width of its parent. The LinearLayout and ImageView in each cell are used to allow for the "turning on and off" of an image within the cell while having the color of the cell persist.

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1,2,3,4,5,6"
    android:background="@drawable/vertical_radio_button_background"
    android:padding="2dp">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/brown"
            android:tag="13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:background="@color/brown">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/selected_check"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/maraschino"
            android:tag="9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:background="@color/maraschino">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/selected_check"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cayenne"
            android:tag="22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:background="@color/cayenne">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/selected_check"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/maroon"
            android:tag="18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:background="@color/maroon">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/selected_check"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/plum"
            android:tag="3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_column="5"
            android:background="@color/plum">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/selected_check"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/eggplant"
            android:tag="15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_column="6"
            android:background="@color/eggplant">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/selected_check"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/plum2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:background="@color/plum">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/selected_check"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lavender"
            android:tag="14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:background="@color/lavender">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/selected_check"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/carnation"
            android:tag="16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:background="@color/carnation">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/selected_check"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/light_pink"
            android:tag="23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:background="@color/light_pink">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/selected_check"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/strawberry"
            android:tag="10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_column="5"
            android:background="@color/strawberry">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/selected_check"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/magenta"
            android:tag="20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_column="6"
            android:background="@color/magenta">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/selected_check"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code for more default application without the buttons, this is very handy for me

```
<GridLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:columnCount="1"
   >
   <TextView
       android:text="2x2 button grid"
       android:textSize="32dip"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal">
       <Space
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1" />
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Naam" />
       <Space
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1" />
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="start"
           android:text="@{viewModel.selectedItem.test2}" />
       <Space
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       >
       <Space
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1" />
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Nummer" />
       <Space
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1" />
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="start"
           android:text="@{viewModel.selectedItem.test}" />
       <Space
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1" />
   </LinearLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here's an example**

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GridMenuActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/oval_background">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/dmm_logo" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
                android:columnCount="2"
                android:columnOrderPreserved="true"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:rowCount="5">

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="3dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_dashboard" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Dashboard"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Add Entry"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="3dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_sell" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Sale Forecast"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Upcoming Milk Requirement"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="3dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_seller" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Sellers"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Milk Providers"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="3dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_shopping" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Purchasers"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Milk Consumers"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


                <!-- Row 2 -->

                <!-- Column 1 -->
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_row="2"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="3dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_advance" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Advance"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Advance Payments"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <!-- Column 2 -->
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_row="2"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="3dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_reciever" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Due"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Pending Payments"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_row="3"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="3dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_transaction" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Transactions"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Payments Detalis"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_row="3"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="3dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_sell" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Sell Product"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Ghee, Curd etc."
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_row="4"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="3dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_purchase_report" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Purchases"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Milk Purchase Entries"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_row="4"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="3dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_sale_report" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Sales"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="Milk Sale Entries"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            </GridLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Perfect for me.
I hope it helps you too

Answer (score 1):

Some tips on Grid layout from Trial and error.

1. Default Grid layout works best on min SDK 21+ .
2. GridLayout's height/width should be either fixed or `match_parent` .It is because Grid layout calculates the height/width of its child, and having the  variable height of its own could cause issues in calculation of the exact height.
3. Grid layout ignores the margins on children by default, so we should be using `android:useDefaultMargins="true"` if we want children to control their margins.
4. To make a dynamic, auto-stretching group of views with Grid layout, either:

   1. the parent would be controlling both: the max height of the total group and number of elements in each row or
   2. the parent would be controlling the number of columns in each row,and the children will be controlling the total height.

the advantage of first scenarios is we can add any number of children in the group and they all will stretch nicely and evenly. the disadvantage becomes that we get a fixed size group. and children with large content also takes a fixed space.

the advantage of second scenario is that we can add more children and they shall decide the height of group. attaching a nested scroll view on the top of parent will make the whole list of elements scrollable.
the disadvantage is that children control the height of group and with variables heights, could cause the whole view to look messy.

if we tweak around a bit, both scenarios could be used for their advantages and their disadvantages could be minimised.

example of first scenario:

```xml
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:useDefaultMargins="true">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
            android:background="@color/black" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"

            android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
            android:background="@color/black" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"

            android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
            android:background="@color/black" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
            android:background="@color/black" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"

            android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
            android:background="@color/black" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"

            android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
            android:background="@color/black" />

     
        <!--        
        add more elements here with same attributes and they will fit on their own!
        -->

    </GridLayout>
```

output:
[image: img1]

second scenario:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    >

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:useDefaultMargins="true"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:text="this is a text"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:text="this is something cool. this should be taking more space but it is also controlling the total height of row"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:text="once the width is determined by any child, the whole column shall take the same height"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:text="this column can only control how they shall look by layout gravity. this should look like column 0,0 but its  taking full row height/width"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            />

        <!--

        -->



    </GridLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

outpus:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by having equal `layout_columnWeight` & `layout_rowWeight`

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="3">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="item 0x0"
        grid:layout_column="0"
        grid:layout_gravity="center"
        grid:layout_row="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="item 0x1"
        grid:layout_column="1"
        grid:layout_gravity="center"
        grid:layout_row="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="item 0x2"
        grid:layout_column="2"
        grid:layout_gravity="center"
        grid:layout_row="0" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="item 1x0"
        grid:layout_column="0"
        grid:layout_gravity="center"
        grid:layout_row="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="item 1x1"
        grid:layout_column="1"
        grid:layout_gravity="center"
        grid:layout_row="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="item 1x2"
        grid:layout_column="2"
        grid:layout_gravity="center"
        grid:layout_row="1" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="item 2x0"
        grid:layout_column="0"
        grid:layout_gravity="center"
        grid:layout_row="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="item 2x1"
        grid:layout_column="1"
        grid:layout_gravity="center"
        grid:layout_row="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="item 2x2"
        grid:layout_column="2"
        grid:layout_gravity="center"
        grid:layout_row="2" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="item 3x0"
        grid:layout_column="0"
        grid:layout_gravity="center"
        grid:layout_row="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="item 3x1"
        grid:layout_column="1"
        grid:layout_gravity="center"
        grid:layout_row="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="item 3x2"
        grid:layout_column="2"
        grid:layout_gravity="center"
        grid:layout_row="3" />

</GridLayout>
```

**Result**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: GridLayout]

```
       <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:background="@drawable/background_down"
        android:layout_height="0dp">


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/user" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Users"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/addusers" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Add Users"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/newspaper" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Report"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
            </LinearLayout>



        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/settings" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Settings"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </GridLayout>
```

you can find the whole tutorials here, 
[Android Grid Layout With CardView and OnItemClickListener](https://youtu.be/C9WqYBv7U1w)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just changed `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `wrap_content` and set `layout_gravity` to `center_horizontal`:

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="4">
```

Answer (score 0):

main.xml

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid_related_news"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:columnCount="2">

</GridLayout>
```

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_related_news"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/light_gray" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="#59000000"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_related_news_title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/yekan_bold"
                android:letterSpacing="-0.1"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                tools:text="@string/lorem_ipsum_sentence" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

java

```
GridLayout grid_related_news = findViewById(R.id.grid_related_news);
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.related_item, (ViewGroup) grid_related_news, false);
ImageView img_related_news = view.findViewById(R.id.img_related_news);
...

grid_related_news.addView(view);
```

You can use this example

Answer (score 0):

I just made simple grid layout out of grid view and was thinking why I didn't do it before. It's so easy to implement. (I use custom wrapper CSView in example but just change it to View). Ops requirement just works in GridView so I posted it here as answer. So to make stretch evenly justy `numColumns:auto_fit android:numColumns=2` for example.

usage:

```
CSGridLayout(this, R.id.sound_store_grid, SubscriptionUpgradeStoreDialogItem(this),
            PresetUpgradeStoreDialogItem(this), MidiUpgradeStoreDialogItem(this))
```

implementation:

```
class CSGridLayout(parent: CSActivityView<*>,
                   viewId: Int,
                   vararg items: CSView<*>) : CSView<GridView>(parent, viewId) {

    private val items = list(items)
    private var adapter = Adapter()

    init {
        view.adapter = adapter
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class Adapter : BaseAdapter() {
        override fun getCount() = items.size
        override fun getViewTypeCount() = 1
        override fun isEnabled(position: Int) = true
        override fun getItem(position: Int) = items[position]
        override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = 0
        override fun getItemId(position: Int) = position.toLong()
        override fun getView(position: Int, toReuseView: View?, parent: ViewGroup) =
            items[position].view
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is what I did and I'm happy to say that this worked for me. I too wanted a 2x2, 3x3 etc. grid of items to cover the entire screen. Gridlayouts do not adhere to the width of the screen. LinearLayouts kind of work but you cant use nested weights.

The best option for me was to use **Fragments** I used [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm) tutorial to get started with what I wanted to do.

Here is some code:

Main Activity:

```
public class GridHolderActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_6);
    }
}
```

activity_main_6 XML (inflates 3 fragments)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frag1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:name=".TwoHorizontalGridFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/two_horiz" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frag2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:name=".TwoHorizontalGridFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/two_horiz" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frag3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:name=".Grid.TwoHorizontalGridFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/two_horiz" />
```

Base fragment layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageQueue
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


    <ImageQueue
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment Class (only handles initialization of a custom view) inflates 2 tiles per fragment

```
public class TwoHorizontalGridFragment extends Fragment {
private View rootView;

private ImageQueue imageQueue1;
private ImageQueue imageQueue2;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /**
     * Inflate the layout for this fragment
     */
    rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.two_horiz, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    imageQueue1 = (ImageQueue)rootView.findViewById(R.id.img1);
    imageQueue2 = (ImageQueue)rootView.findViewById(R.id.img2);
    imageQueue1.updateFiles();
    imageQueue2.updateFiles();
}
```

}

Thats it!

This is a weird work around to using nested weights, essentially. It gives me a perfect 2x3 grid that fills the entire screen of both my 10 inch tablet and my HTC droid DNA. Let me know how it goes for you!

Comment: This is a bad approach as you are having multiple fragments which have a whole lot of complex structure to do a simple taks that can be achieved by using a gridview/gridlayout.

Comment: The OP said they needed a 2x2 grid for a few buttons. Youre right, this is way to complex. For layouts with more text, views and other content, fragments are the way to go. Also, this would only be useful if the layouts were totally static and NOT dynamically built.

Comment: Now that there is more support for GridLayouts in API 21, this approach is overkill