# Android gridlayout overflowing screen

Tags: android, grid-layout

I have this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="8"
    android:rowCount="8" >

    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

</GridLayout>
```

And its giving me this:

[image]

Its supposed to be an 8x8 grid but it's overflowing. How can I, non-programmatically, (through xml) fit the 64 squares?

Comment: Looks like your images are too big for the gridlayout to fit to the screen when using row count. Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10033481/758341) will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:columnCount="8"
    android:rowCount="8" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"    
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"    
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"    
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"    
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"    
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"    
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"    
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"    
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
    </LinearLayout>


</GridLayout>
```

Comment: this helped me too.. but just a small question.. this implementation doesn't use the flexibility that GridLayout supposed to offer, using row and column spans. Is there a way to achieve the same layout, to fit the height and width of the screen, using row and column of GridLayout?

Answer (score 10):

you might also want to checkout http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/gridlayout-view-clipping-issues.html

here's the key info from that page incase it get's deleted:

use the following in you last (right most) view

```
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it for every layout.

```
   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageButton 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"    
            android:layout_weight="1"  />
         <ImageButton 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"    
            android:layout_weight="1"  />
 <ImageButton 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"    
            android:layout_weight="1"  />
 <ImageButton 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"    
            android:layout_weight="1"  />
 <ImageButton 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"    
            android:layout_weight="1"  />
 <ImageButton 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"    
            android:layout_weight="1"  />
 <ImageButton 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"    
            android:layout_weight="1"  />
 <ImageButton 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"    
            android:layout_weight="1"  />
        </LinearLayout>
```