# Android show images in GridView

Tags: android, image, gridview

Hi I am pretty new to android and I am basically stuck. I have some paths of images (e.g. String Path) and I want to display these images on a `GridView`.

This is the class which practically inflates a layout composed of a `GridView`.

```
public class FragmentLayout extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //String path = "/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.android.browser/files/Download/2014-01-10-00-13-39--1894493676.jpeg";

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Any guidelines please?

Comment: Read [THIS](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html), after that [THIS](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: so you just want to display images in gridView or something special?

Comment: no just display the image in a gridview

Comment: till now I have only one path, but I may have more than one that's why  I am using a gridView and not an imageview...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a newbie to android, you might be better off going with a third-party library than writing your own container for images in a gridview. Caching and load times will be an issue most people don't think of. Take a look at this thread:

[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

LazyList (specifically, this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8562313/2066079) might be a huge help to you, though it might be overkill.

If you know the paths beforehand, you can make them a drawable, create an `ImageView` for each, and then throw them in a `GridLayout`. the reason I choose `GridLayout` over `GridView` is for compatibility with older devices.

To make the images fill the Grid container, I found this post: very useful: [GridLayout (not GridView) how to stretch all children evenly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016343/gridlayout-not-gridview-how-to-stretch-all-children-evenly/15341447#15341447)
But like I said - caching and load times will be an issue if the images are large, or if there are more than a handful of them.

Answer (score 0):

SEE these examples for help

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/

http://androidprogramz.blogspot.in/2012/07/display-images-in-gridview.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_grid_view.htm

You can do this for chaging images or just create array of drawables

```
if (mobile.equals("Windows")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.windows_logo);
            } else if (mobile.equals("iOS")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ios_logo);
            } else if (mobile.equals("Blackberry")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blackberry_logo);
            } else {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_logo);
            }
```

**OR**

```
ArrayList<Integer> myImageList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myImageList.add(R.drawable.thingOne);
// later...
myImageView.setImageResouce(myImageList.get(i));
```

Comment: my main problem is that I am not sure of how i shall change the image path of string into an R.drawable.pic_1

Answer (score 0):

If they are just static images, copy them into your drawable folder then you can pretty use the exact example which is on the android docs about grid view:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html