# GridLayout wide childrens

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

It seems GridLayout isn't capable of handling wide Views correctly.

Here's my simple layout:

```
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2">

<TextView
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:text="1,1"/>

<TextView
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:text="LongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLongLong"/>
```

[image]

Is there a way to make this work?

Actually I want 3 column layout where the 2nd would stretch, but first I'd like to get around this simple issue.

Comment: Did you look this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016343/gridlayout-not-gridview-how-to-stretch-all-children-evenly?rq=1 ?

Comment: @deathember Doesn't look relevant.