# View half of its parent's height and width

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I make an android view half of its parent's width and height? Something like the starred part here:

```
+-------|-------+
|*******|       |
|*******|       |
|*******|       |
|*******|       |
|*******|       |
|*******|       |
|-------|-------|
|       |       |
|       |       |
|       |       |
|       |       |
|       |       |
|       |       |
+-------|-------+
```

**Edit**

Anyone reading this question, you are better off using AppCompat `GridLayout` and use `column_weight` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30245753/1812633) as nested weights are expensive.

Comment: One way would be drawing a two lines along the mid-section both with 0dp width and aligning your View relative to those lines.

Comment: But my issue is not alignment, its size. I can use align_parent_top or something like that to align them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some fake layouts and and Layout Weight must do the trick..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dummy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="invisible" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dummy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="invisible" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dummy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="invisible" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways to do so - depends a bit on the context - but one way would be to use layout_weight