# Most efficient way to set column width in table layout?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I'm working on an real estate application.

On the detail page of a house I display a lot of info about the house.
But I'm getting some warnings that my layout takes too long to render so I'm looking to improve my layout.

This is the part of my layout I want to improve:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp">

        <!-- General -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/view_property_properties_general"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <!-- Interior -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/view_property_properties_interior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <!-- Financial -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/view_property_properties_financial"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <!-- Terrain -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/view_property_properties_terrain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <!-- Energy -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/view_property_properties_energy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is what the general properties layout looks like (I'm using a expandable panel so the user can show/hide):

```
<widgets.ExpandablePanel
android:id="@+id/general_container"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:content="@+id/content"
app:handle="@+id/tv_general_title">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_general_title"
    style="@style/property_detail_title_style"
    android:text="@string/general_properties"/>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
            android:text="@string/estate_type"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_estate_type"
            style="@style/property_detail_value_style"
            tools:text="House"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
            android:text="@string/total_living_area"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_liveable_area"
            style="@style/property_detail_value_style"
            tools:text="145 m²"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
            android:text="@string/number_of_facades"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_number_of_facades"
            style="@style/property_detail_value_style"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
            android:text="@string/number_of_living_units"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_number_of_living_units"
            style="@style/property_detail_value_style"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
            android:text="@string/number_of_floors"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_number_of_floors"
            style="@style/property_detail_value_style"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
            android:text="@string/number_of_extra_buildings"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_number_of_extra_buildings"
            style="@style/property_detail_value_style"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
            android:text="@string/parking_spots_inside"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_parking_spots_inside"
            style="@style/property_detail_value_style"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
            android:text="@string/parking_spots_outside"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_parking_spots_outside"
            style="@style/property_detail_value_style"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
            android:text="@string/condition_of_the_building"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_condition_of_the_building"
            style="@style/property_detail_value_style"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
            android:text="@string/length_on_streetside"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_width_on_streetside"
            style="@style/property_detail_value_style"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
            android:text="@string/year"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_build_year"
            style="@style/property_detail_value_style"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
            android:text="@string/investment_property"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_investment_property"
            style="@style/property_detail_value_style"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
            android:text="@string/public_sale_property"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_public_sale"
            style="@style/property_detail_value_style"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
            android:text="@string/newbuild"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_newbuild"
            style="@style/property_detail_value_style"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            style="@style/property_detail_label_style"
            android:text="@string/seasight"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_seasight"
            style="@style/property_detail_value_style"/>

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

These are the styles:

```
 <style name="property_detail_label_style">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/between_small_and_medium_fontsize</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/gray_6</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">0.6</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
</style>

<style name="property_detail_value_style">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/between_small_and_medium_fontsize</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/gray_6</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">0.4</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left|center_vertical</item>
</style>
```

As you can see I'm giving the 'label' TextView and the 'value' TextView a weight. I know that weights are expensive but what are the alternatives ?

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: "my layout takes too long to render" where did you get that warning from? (It should be just the layout part that isn't re-done all the time that is affected by weights - maybe your problem aren't those weights after all?) You could try if GridLayout with some hacks ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/15341447/995891 ) works for you

Comment: If you're going to use weight in a TableLayout you might as well drop the TableLayout and replace each TableRow with a simple Linearlayout, this way you at least flatten the view hierarchy by one. The main problem is that you're nesting a lot of views in a deep hierarchy. At a quick look your view suggest an `ExpandableListView` with the "includes" being the group rows and the actual data for each group being the child rows.