# Gridlayout preivew is right but on real device gets compressed

Tags: android, android-layout, grid-layout, android-gridlayout, gridlayoutmanager

I am new to `Gridlayout` in android, but i create a layout which looks fine on preview screens but when i run it on real device all items gets compressed and get aligned to top-left of screen

This layout is perfect when we see preview on android studio or eclipse with all items having equally stretched or width but on real device it gets compressed to left of layout

My xml is as follows,i need help in sortring out this error:-

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <GridLayout
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:useDefaultMargins="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/backgournd_cancel"
                    android:columnCount="4">

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/style_textView_marquee"
                            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
                            android:text="Vikramaa" />

                        <ImageView
                           style="@style/style_imageView"
                            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                             android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"  />

                        <ImageView
                            style="@style/style_imageView"
                            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/edit_pressed" />

                        <ImageView
                            style="@style/style_imageView"
                            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/heart_normal" />

                        <ImageView
                            style="@style/style_imageView"
                            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/open_pressed" />

                </GridLayout>
```

Comment: this might be helpful http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I tried to accomplish this layout through many ways including this also, but failed any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the screen resolution of your real device?

Comment: but it will make constants, i have to use laylout_width as match parent...

Comment: Now, this code works without any change of single line...I don't know how it happens may be due to change of theme

Answer (score 0):

This should resolve your issue please [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016343/gridlayout-not-gridview-how-to-stretch-all-children-evenly#answer-10033481) this answer from @HenrikS for more details

```
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="1"
>
    <TextView
        android:text="2x2 button grid"
        android:textSize="32dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:text="Button 2" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 3" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:text="Button 4" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: then what is the advantage of using grid layout, i can accomplish this with the use of relative and linear layout....but thanks revolution.

Comment: There are limitations when using the GridLayout. See the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html