# Extra Space in TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am very new to android app development.In the below code, I am using TableLayout to place my contents but getting some extra spaces in table row. Please suggest how to remove it.

```
 <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="DataStage 8.5"
            android:id="@+id/textViewDS8.5"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:textColor="#090909"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>
```

[image: Extra Space In App]

Comment: Are you wanting the text to appear in the center together or have the right column appear where the arrows are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In place of using TableRow you can use gridlayout

[GridLayout (not GridView) how to stretch all children evenly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016343/gridlayout-not-gridview-how-to-stretch-all-children-evenly)

this is almost the similar or you can use linear layout and set its orientation horizantal and set the weight of the text view 0.5 in this way both the text will cover half the screen and no free space