# Preview resize in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to learn Android, but I got problem with Preview. When i change resolution to 5.0 it doesnt show my preview. On other resolutions it works.

This is not working version.
[image]

And this is my working version
[image: And this is my working version]

XML Code:

```
pastebin.com/EWvmrSXD
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to share xml code?

Comment: of course, do you need only layouts?

Comment: Yes it seems layout would be enough

Comment: https://pastebin.com/EWvmrSXD - this is layout for my buttons. I think the problem is here

Comment: Can you please edit the question and copy the code in the question instead of just giving a link.

Comment: If theme does not fix issue then it seems support lib issue.Check following link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39954438/how-to-support-layout-columnweight-and-layout-rowweight-in-pre-api-21/39954659?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing AppTheme at top of the preview.

Comment: what theme should i choose?

Comment: @Rocky3582 What error you get at the bottom of preview

Comment: @Rocky3582 Choose any Material theme like Material.Light

Comment: whats your application theme? send those files