# Why are adjacent Buttons moving when I change the size of the text in a Button

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is the layout when each `Button` has the same size text:

[image]

And here is the layout when I increase the size of the bottom right `Button`'s text:

[image]

What's going on here? Why is the "0" `Button` moving lower than the two `Buttons` adjacent to it?

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:background="@android:color/white"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="6dp">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/input_textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="3">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_1_button"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_2_button"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="2"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_3_button"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="3"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_4_button"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="4"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_5_button"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="5"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_6_button"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="6"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_7_button"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="7"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_8_button"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="8"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_9_button"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="9"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/the_backspace_button"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_backspace"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/the_0_button"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="0"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/the_done_button"
                android:layout_width="88dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:minWidth="0dp"
                android:minHeight="0dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:text="done"/>
    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

### Update:

I made the text of the "DONE" `Button` super large -- 100sp -- and set `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` for it equal to the height and width of the other `Buttons`. Here is the result:

[image]
*the blue is the `GridLayout`'s background, the red the "0" `Button's`, and the yellow the "DONE" `Button's`

Why would changing the size of the text of the "DONE" Button affect anything other than that specific `Button` if the size of the `Button` never changes?

Comment: I cannot answer your specific question, but setting `android:layout_gravity="top"` on `android:id="@+id/the_0_button"` should move the `Button`. You should go through the source code and see how `GridLayout` is measuring & laying out its children.

Comment: @Vikram tried that. didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem with the done button. You set the background of it. Then you also set its text as "done" .

Just set it text empty and the problem may resolve ;)

Comment: the button must have the text

Comment: "-" is not an image it's a literal hyphen. when the text size changes the text also changes to "-"

Comment: if you look at the first image, you'll see "done" as the button text

Answer (score 1):

What about using the grid:layout_rowWeight or grid:layout_rowHeight attributes to be the same for every button?

Look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32291319/2205825

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the GridLayout is reserving enough height for the actual text size and some default padding despite the layout_height for the Done button.

Answer (score 1):

Try this .....

Use `GridView` instead of many `Button` that not give you any Layout problem **(Adjustment of Views)**.

Have look on the **below example** that solve your problem about **Adjustment of Buttons**

> use this `layout` instead of your layout .....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/input_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> add these 2 line in your `OnCreate` method .....

```
  GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this));
```

> add this adapter in your project .....

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

/**
 * Created by sushildlh on 10/14/16.
 */
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    // Keep all Images in array
    public String[] text = {
            "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "", "0", "DONE"
    };

    // Constructor
    public CustomAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return 12;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new textView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder = null;
        if (holder == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
            holder = new Holder();
            holder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            holder.image = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (position != 9) {
            holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.button.setText(text[position]);
        } else {
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_backspace_black_24dp);    //change ic_backspace_black_24dp into to your image ......
            holder.button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;

    }

    public static class Holder {
        Button button;
        ImageButton image;
    }


}
```

> and this is item.xml layout into your layout folder ....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textSize="25dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> above code give you the output like this ....

[image: oupput]

**Note:- Always use `GridView` OR `ListView` for same pattern of Views .....**

Comment: how did you prevent the `GridView` from scrolling?

Comment: where you getting scroll in the answer ?

Comment: `GridViews` scroll

Comment: nvm. for some reason it's not scrolling anymore.

Comment: also, you'll note that the background for my buttons are white, and yet you made yours transparent -- eliminating having to deal with borders showing and animations not showing. but my buttons must be white, without borders, and with the default animations. that's why i liked `GridLayout` because i got all of those things; disregarding the strange "0" button behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the android:layout_weight property.

Answer (score 0):

Build it with 'Linear Layouts' instead.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Was facing the same problem, so just i did was to change the height and width of the button to it parent RowTable's match parent & wrap content and it solved my problem

Comment: u can see in Picture Attached