# gridview elements fitting the screen

Tags: android, gridview, layout, screen-size

I am implementing an android application and I want to display something like the following picture, with an imageview and textview inside each square of the gridview but I am not able to have all the items fitting the whole screen. I have a limited nummber of items to show and I just want to put them fitting all the screen for any screen size without calculating dimensions and this. Can you help me?? Thanks.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.rafad.betasentit.MainActivity">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/appsGridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:numColumns="2">
</GridView>
</FrameLayout>
```

item.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: "I don't want it scrollable" - Then don't use a `GridView`. Use some other static `ViewGroup`; e.g., `GridLayout`, `TableLayout`, etc.

Comment: @MikeM. but GridLayout just allows to set single elements as its items, right? I cannot put load the file item.xml as an item of the layout as I do with gridview,, isn't it?

Comment: Nah, you can nest `View`s in `GridLayout` just like you would in any other `ViewGroup`. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10033481.