# Adding equally sized views dynamically in GridLayout

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I need to show a 4x10 grid of random colors. The grid should fill the screen horizontally and vertically, and all cells should be of equal dimensions. Since the grid (4x10) dimensions can change in the future, GridLayout made more sense to me than TableLayout. GridView and RecyclerView are out because I don't need any scrolling behavior.

Since I need to add these child views at runtime, I started with calculating cell width and height as a ration of screen width and height. Then I stumbled across [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016343/gridlayout-not-gridview-how-to-stretch-all-children-evenly) which says GridLayout has better ways to achieve such behavior. There is a code example for static (XML) based views, but I am not able to find a Java/Kotlin example. I am experimenting with [GridLayout.Spec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.Spec) to use in the LayoutParams for the child views, but can't figure out how it works.

Updated with a screenshot of desired layout. This image is 12x10, but I want the flexibility to change the dimensions (compile time).

[image]

Comment: It would be more helpful if you can share a screenshot (what you want to achieve) or your xml layout to be more precise.

Comment: Added a screenshot. My layout has an empty GridLayout as of now because I want to add the color cells dynamically - and that's where I am stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to LinearLayout, there is a weight attribute in GridLayout spec - which you can set to 1 for all views. Similar to LinearLayout, make the width and height 0 using weights. Use Undefined as position as you want to draw the views in sequence, else pass the corresponding position for each cell.

```
    gridLayout.rowCount = rowCount
    gridLayout.columnCount = colCount

    for (i in 1..rowCount*colCount){
        val layoutParams: GridLayout.LayoutParams = GridLayout.LayoutParams(
                GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f),
                GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f)).apply {
            width = 0
            height = 0
        }

        val blueView = View(this).apply {
            setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
        }
        gridLayout.addView(blueView, layoutParams)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        If you want to generate grid layout col and row dynamically you can use grid layout with recycler view. 

        1. xml code 

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                />
                </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


     2 create a model classs as per your requriement

    public class AllAssignedTableModel {

        @SerializedName("table_id")
        private int table_id;

        @SerializedName("table_name")
        private String table_name;

        @SerializedName("restaurant_id")
        private int restaurant_id;

        @SerializedName("waiter_id")
        private int waiter_id;

        @SerializedName("image")
        private String image;

        @SerializedName("table_status")
        private int table_status;

        @SerializedName("table_bill")
        private double table_bill;

        public String getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public void setImage(String image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        public int getTable_id() {
            return table_id;
        }

        public void setTable_id(int table_id) {
            this.table_id = table_id;
        }

        public String getTable_name() {
            return table_name;
        }

        public void setTable_name(String table_name) {
            this.table_name = table_name;
        }

        public int getRestaurant_id() {
            return restaurant_id;
        }

        public void setRestaurant_id(int restaurant_id) {
            this.restaurant_id = restaurant_id;
        }

        public int getWaiter_id() {
            return waiter_id;
        }

        public void setWaiter_id(int waiter_id) {
            this.waiter_id = waiter_id;
        }

        public int getTable_status() {
            return table_status;
        }

        public void setTable_status(int table_status) {
            this.table_status = table_status;
        }

        public double getTable_bill() {
            return table_bill;
        }

        public void setTable_bill(double table_bill) {
            this.table_bill = table_bill;
        }
    }


        3. create adapter of recycler view as per your requirement.

        package talent4assure.com.manageyourrestaurant.adapter;

        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.SharedPreferences;
        import android.graphics.Color;
        import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
        import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
        import android.text.TextUtils;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.LinearLayout;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
        import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;
        import com.google.gson.Gson;


        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.List;

        import talent4assure.com.manageyourrestaurant.R;
        import talent4assure.com.manageyourrestaurant.model.AllAssignedTableModel;

        import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;


        public class WaAssignedTableListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WaAssignedTableListAdapter.EmployeeViewHolder> {
        private Context context;
            private List<AllAssignedTableModel> dataList;

           // public ImageView img;


            public static final String MY_BILL_PREFS = "MyBillPrefsFile";
            String tableId,billAmount;
            HashMap<String, String> billMap=new HashMap<String, String>();

            public WaAssignedTableListAdapter(List<AllAssignedTableModel> dataList, Context context) {

                this.dataList = dataList;
                this.context=context;
            }



            @Override
            public EmployeeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
                View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.waiter_cards_layout, parent, false);
                return new EmployeeViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(EmployeeViewHolder holder, int position) {
                holder.tvAssignTableName.setText(dataList.get(position).getTable_name());
                holder.tvCustomerBill.setText(String.valueOf(dataList.get(position).getTable_bill()));

                int status = dataList.get(position).getTable_status();

                if(status == 1){
                    holder.llBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.llred_background);

                }else {
                    holder.llBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.llblue_background);
                }
            }



            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return dataList.size();
            }

            class EmployeeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

                TextView tvAssignTableName,tvCustomerBill;

                LinearLayout llBackground;


                EmployeeViewHolder(View itemView) {
                    super(itemView);
                    tvAssignTableName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAssignTableName);
                    tvCustomerBill = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCustomerBill);
                    llBackground = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.llBackground);

                }
            }

        }



        4. java class activity code 

         no of column u can pass statically or you can pass val dynamically as per your requirement(in this example i am taking it as 4). and no of row will get created as per your data dynamically. hope it will help you.

        private WaAssignedTableListAdapter adapter;
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;




recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());        

        adapter = new WaAssignedTableListAdapter(allAssignedTableModels, WaiterActivity.this);

                                    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 4, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
                                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```