# pointing android xml layout to reference library

Tags: android, reference, android-gridlayout, reference-library

Needing to use `GridLayout` in my android 2.2 project, I import the reference library from `/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/support/v7/gridlayout`. When I clean the project, the red underlines go away. But as soon as I try editing the xml layout file, the error returns:

```
View requires API level 14 (current min is 8): 
<GridLayout>
```

So how do I get the layout file to point to the API 7 grid layout?

Answer (score 0):

You might have read [How to make Android GridLayout compatible to older version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126780/how-to-make-android-gridlayout-compatible-to-older-version). If not, I suggest you to go through. You said that  you imported the reference library. But after importing it you also need to `reference` this library project to your working project. `Right click your project -> Properties. Select`Android`on the left and`Add`... Select the imported workspace library. It will show with green sign.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do as you said, the red underline didn't go away. So I clean and it went away. But then as soon as I make an edit the red returns. So basically your suggestion made completely no difference. But I will read the link.

Comment: doing `<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout ...>` seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I just realize the change cause all my formatting to go away. It basically treat my work as a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation.